# Gnuplot combining 'plot for' and 'paste'

Tags: variables, loops, for-loop, gnuplot, paste

The following code executes perfectly:

```
do for [i=1:$M_Orbs]{
set table 'L_z_'.i.'.dat'
plot [0:250] "L_z_expectation.dat" u 1:2+2*((i-1)*$M_Orbs+i) smooth cspline w l
unset table

set table 'Nocc_'.i.'.dat'
plot [0:250] "NO_PR.out"  u 1:2+$M_Orbs-i smooth cspline t 'M='.i w l
unset table
}
```

But I have trouble when I try and combine these files in a loop using the paste command:

```
plot for [i=1:$M_Orbs] '< paste 'L_z_'.i.'.dat' 'Nocc_'.i.'.dat'' u 1:(\$2*\$5)
```

This line brings up the error,

```
plot for [i=1:2] '< paste 'L_z_'.i.'.dat' 'Nocc_'.i.'.dat'' u 1:($2*$5) 
                           ^
       line 0: x range is invalid
```

I'm pretty sure the error occurs because gnuplot tries to execute the paste command before assigning i to it's value in the for loop. Is there another way of escaping the i, or atleast implimenting the same idea in another way?

Comment: Have you tried double quotes ie: `plot for [i=1:$M_Orbs] "< paste 'L_z_'.i.'.dat' 'Nocc_'.i.'.dat" u 1:(\$2*\$5)`

Comment: @ctheo You are right, the quotes are the problem, but your version doesn't work either. You won't get an error anymore, but the string is treated 'as is', without building it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong quotes.

Inside single quotes `'` you can use either double quotes `"` without escaping them, or double single quotes `''` (which is the way single quotes are escaped).

But the filenames given to `paste` mustn't be quoted, so your plot command becomes:

```
plot for [i=1:$M_Orbs] '< paste L_z_'.i.'.dat Nocc_'.i.'.dat' u 1:(column(2)*column(5))
```

`column(2)` is the long version of `$2`, but must not be escaped.

You could also use `sprintf` to format your file names:

```
plot for [i=1:$M_Orbs] '< paste '.sprintf('L_z_%d.dat Nocc_%d.dat', i, i) u 1:(\$2*\$5)
```

I prefer the latter variant, because it allows you e.g. to pad the numbers with zeros: `sprintf('L_z_%03d.dat', )`.